# Run array formula based on selected cell range and copy results to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do the following:

Highlight a vertical range of cells, perform an array formula on that range, and push the results into my clipboard (preferably by pushing a hotkey).

For reference, here is the array formula:  `=LEFT(CONCAT("'"&TRIM(UNIQUE(A:A))&"',"),LEN(CONCAT("'"&TRIM(UNIQUE(A:A))&"',"))-1)`

The A:A range above needs to dynamically reflect the cells highlighted (almost always a vertical column).

How do I refer to highlighted cells and put them into the array, and push results to the clipboard?

Here's a table and example

| Column A |
| --- |
| AAA |
| BBB |
| CCC |

I'd highlight, for instance, cells A2:A4, press the macro button to run the formula
`=LEFT(CONCAT("'"&TRIM(UNIQUE(A2:A4))&"',"),LEN(CONCAT("'"&TRIM(UNIQUE(A2:A4))&"',"))-1)`

and copy the following text to the clipboard
`'AAA','BBB','CCC'`

Comment: Not sure what you need. Can you share example of starting data and desired output?

Comment: Sure, we're often taking large columnar data sets and transposing them into concatenated, comma+quote separated rows for SQL where in() fields. I'd like to be able to select a column of data, run it through the array formula at the push of the button, and copy the results to clipboard. 

`AAA`

`BBB`

`CCC`

copies to the clipboard as

`'AAA','BBB','CCC'`

Comment: Can you make a table of sample data? Trying to relate your formula to that statement and it doesn't exactly match. Show us a sample table of the input data

Comment: `="'" & TEXTJOIN("', '",TRUE,UNIQUE(A:A)) & "'"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do this type of thing.

You can set the clipboard text using the Win API: it's also possible using `DataObject` but that seems pretty unreliable on Win10.

```vba
Sub tester()
    Dim s As String, arr
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        arr = GetUniques(Selection)
        If UBound(arr) = -1 Then Exit Sub 'no values found
        s = "'" & Join(arr, "','") & "'"
        'Debug.Print s 
        SetClipboard s 'set to clipboard: see below
    End If
End Sub

Function GetUniques(rng As Range) 'as array
    Dim c As Range, dict, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = 0
    Next c
    GetUniques = dict.Keys
End Function
```

There may be some additions you'd need to make if your input lists are very large, depending on your database flavor. Eg. `IN` lists for Oracle are restricted to 1000 or fewer items so you need to use something like `col IN([first 1000 items]) OR col IN([rest of items])`

Edit - full Win API code for setting clipboard.  Put this in a separate module.  Will need adjustments if you're running 64-bit Excel.

```VBA
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Long, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

Public Sub SetClipboard(sUniText As String)
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
    Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
    OpenClipboard 0&
    EmptyClipboard
    iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
    iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
    iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
    lstrcpy iLock, StrPtr(sUniText)
    GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
    CloseClipboard
End Sub

Public Function GetClipboard() As String
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    Dim sUniText As String
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = 13&
    OpenClipboard 0&
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) Then
        iStrPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
        If iStrPtr Then
            iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
            iLen = GlobalSize(iStrPtr)
            sUniText = String$(iLen \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
            lstrcpy StrPtr(sUniText), iLock
            GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
        End If
        GetClipboard = sUniText
    End If
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - getting this into the clipboard is proving to be difficult... do you have a recommended strategy?  I'm not sure how to link the two chunks of code.

Comment: See edits above - I tested the first solution on the page I had linked and it wasn't working for me, so I added the Win API code I generally use.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're on 64-bit, are the updates required easy enough to find on my own?  I'm pretty new.  Thanks again for holding man hand through this!

Comment: See  https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit  I'm on 32-bit so can't test for 64-bit

Comment: Awesome!  I got it working.  If you're interested, I'd be happy to share my AutoHotkey macro that does this same thing.  IT security decided we can't use AHK anymore, so you've literally saved my day.  Thank you so much.